# Need help desperately to decrypt home folder

Tags: ecryptfs

Okay, long story:

My Windows crashed so I installed 11.10 on my HDD. I then partitioned my 1TB so I could dual boot both OSes. But now when I go to log into my Ubuntu system it says "missing operating system". I went to recover ALL OF MY DATA from that machine using `ext2explore` on my Windows machine to find that they are all encrypted!

I have booted with a LiveCD and done the mounting and all the steps to access the encrypted files from there but each time I go to `chroot` it tells me a `/bash/bin` format error.

I really need help on how to get my data out of the encryption either with fixing my Ubuntu OS or something.

If you need more clarification on something please let me know, I'm just a little stressed on losing everything I have because I encrypted it and can't get it back.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/recover-your-encrypted-private-directory-using-ecryptfs-recover-private.html) for recovering encrypted directories. Boot from your Ubuntu Install CD, click "Try Ubuntu", and good luck!

Before you `chroot`, do a `file /path/to/chroot/bin/bash` and `ldd /path/to/chroot/bin/bash`. It should say (it says on my working system):

```
$ file /bin/bash  
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped  
$ ldd /bin/bash  
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff689ff000)  
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f0670ea4000)  
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0670ca0000)  
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0670900000)  
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f06706d9000)  
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f06710f3000)
```

or, you could replace (in your `chroot` command) `/bin/bash` with `/bin/static-sh` (if you have the `busybox-static` package installed.